# 1 Cube 1 Square 1 Line

Tags: dissection, paper-folding

Lets take a 1'x 1'x 1' Cube rock and a 1' x 1' Square paper. With 1 straight Line cut of a scissors we can create a hole on the foldable Square paper where the Cube rock can pass through without tearing the paper. How can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a classic. Any zig-zag pattern will do e.g. (sorry for the bad drawing):

[image: Zig-zag]

To get the cut, first we have to concertina fold like this, leaving a bit on each end which we make sure not to cut under any circumstances (this can be achieved by folding the bits it out of the way of any cuts that will harm it:

[image: Concertina with bits on the side]

Then we need to fold the thin rectangle like this:

[image: Special fold]

And cut like this:

[image: One cut!]

Then unfold, making first this (the coloured lines should be parallel):

[image: Parllel folds and cuts]

Then this:

[image: Undone concertina]

*(the second pair of triangles shouldn't overlap, it's my bad drawing)*

Then we gently unravel the long wiggly sheet of paper ignoring the extra triangles (e.g. holding the top and letting the rest fall down) and hey presto, we have a big loop with a hole for the rock to go through!

Comment: ^vote with a note: With a little more folding, the cut can probably be one straight line

Comment: @humn Just finding a solution, not necessarily the best! ;)

Comment: @ boboquack- 1 fold wont work. We should  try this with real 1x1 paper and scissors.

Comment: Note that the puzzle statement does explicitly say a single *straight line* cut. So this works only in so far as humn is right.

Comment: I'll edit once I finish better diagrams for the folding.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I've made the folds and cut better.

Comment: Looks good! (Though I haven't checked any of the details.)

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify the zigzag cut above with 2 folds. First we fold in half then fold again about the diagonal on the side with fold. Through the first fold between the corner of diagonal fold and top edge of paper, cut straight through the edge of the triangle. This will cut off the center triangle and make a V-cut that is a little longer than cube side.

[image]